# Visual Studio Code - Live Server - Html Displays but no CSS markup

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have used VSC with LiveServer for some years with only 1 problem, back a few years ago when either LiveServer or Windows10 had an update installed, next time I opened my HTML file in LiveServer, the HTML was rendered in a "basic" layout, and did not include my CSS Styles.

On an Internet search I found a solution for either this site or similar where I needed to add a line of code to either LS or Windows, sorry but I cant remember which. And all was well again until, now. The very same problem has returned, and no matter how much I search, I cant fine the solution.

There are plenty where there were errors in HTML or CSS, but this is occurring on files which haven't changed, and on new ones from the same master I use for my new pages. The screenshot included shows the HTML, LS as basic HTML and how the page loads on the browser directly. I am using Chrome, but have tried on Firefox with same results.

[How LS displays and how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDUyT.jpg)

Comment: Please read [ask] and don't post pictures of code. The actual source of your problem is half covered up by another window in that screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your VS Code project from a directory that contains your HTML **and** CSS.

Your HTML document is in the root directory of your project (hence the URL being `/filename`) but you are trying to load CSS from `../../css/filename`.

The project needs to be two directories higher for the webserver to include that path.

Comment: How stupid of me. Thanks for the prompt reply and sorry for such an obvious error. I had been working on a new project and then re-opened my main project in the wrong folder. Thanks, it all works fine again.